# description of SVM file format

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, dataformat

I have a data set that is on SVM format. 
There is simple of one row:

```
-1 4:0.0788382 5:0.124138 6:0.117647 11:0.428571 16:0.1 17:0.749633 18:0.843029 19:0.197344 21:0.142856 22:0.142857 23:0.142857 28:1 33:0.0555556 41:0.1 54:1 56:1 64:1 70:1 72:1 74:1 76:1 82:1 84:1 86:1 88:1 90:1 92:1 94:1 96:1 1
```

Could somebody give a description of this file pls? How to read this format?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to SVM; it's a generic columnar format.
The first entry (-1 in this example) is the label for the observation.
The other entries are pairs of `feature_number : value` entries.

In your given observation, the label (classification) is -1 (likely "bad event").  The first four features (0-3) have no value.  Features 4-6 have the indicated values; 7-10 are missing.  This continues through the end of the line.  I'm not sure what the trailing `1` value means; this syntax is new to me.